# Consume web service(.asmx) in .NetCore (through connected services)

Tags: asp.net-core

Am trying to consume client *.asmx* webservice in .Net Core using Connected Services and my service method returns more than 100000 data and  when called particular method am getting below error

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element

To do this my project doesn't have any *app.config* file.

Please let me know how to handle this.

```
WebAPISoapClient soapClient = new WebAPISoapClient();
GetAllLicenceDetailsResponse = await soapClient.GetAllLicenceDetailsAsync();
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server side?

Comment: How did you create the `WebAPISoapClient`? As my test, connected service will create the soapclient with `EndpointConfiguration` parameter like `public WebService1SoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(WebService1SoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), WebService1SoapClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))`. And for `WebService1SoapClient`, it will set `result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;`. Share us your current `Reference.cs`